# Importing videos from ipad to pc

Tags: ipad

I have an iPad pro and a laptop (with windows), and when Im exporting videos to my laptop, I cannot run them and get an error "HEVC video extension needed". This is the default video player of windows. Do you have any suggestions for a video player that would work fine with the imported videos from my iPad?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Windows doesn't support HEVC natively - you need an extension - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/hevc-video-extensions/9nmzlz57r3t7?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

[VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) will play them without that extension package.